# Tried disabling an extension, now I get a Fatal Error

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I tried to disable a magento extension by setting it as "False" in /public_html/app/etc/modules/{extension folder} but now I am receiving an error

"Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Enquireproducts_Helper_Data' not found in /home/devbseatedglobal/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 546"

Why is this happening?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: @Enigmativity This actually is about programming, although it doesn't sound like it.  The meta programming systems that implement Magento are malfunctioning and causing the system to attempt to instantiate a class that doesn't exist.

Comment: @AlanStorm - I appreciate that there can be a bit of a grey area between configuration and programming, but this does sound more like configuration to me. Your answer certainly sounds that way. I think that the OP should be a little clearer on the programming aspect of this question for it to be on-topic.

Comment: @Enigmativity When I say "I disabled the extension by setting it as false" I actually mean I went in the code and set it to False: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
 <modules>
  <Vikont_Enquireproducts>
   <active>False</active>
   <codePool>local</codePool>
  </Vikont_Enquireproducts>
 </modules>
</config>

And the module is still being used..

Comment: @user110230 - I think the distinction is that the XML is config, not code. It's a bit the same as going in to the `core_config_data` table and changing some settings there. It's not really coding. I get that it is a grey area and there are times that data is code. In this case it really seems to be config to me.

Comment: @user110230 - Here is what is on-topic: (1) a specific programming problem, or (2) a software algorithm, or (3) software tools commonly used by programmers; and is (4) a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development. That's from the site help. I don't think that this question falls under those.

Answer (score 0):

The extension probably has an XML file that has an attribute that looks something like this.

```
module="enquireproducts"
```

This XML instruction tells Magento to load the module's data helper to translate a string.

When Magento loads all those XML files, it places them into a cache so it only needs to load them once.  Although you've disabled the extension, my guess is there's still a cached XML file somewhere.  Try manually clearing your cache.  (If you're running stock, cache files are stored in `/var/cache/*` -- you can clear them by deleting them)

It's also possible **a different** extension has XML configured that includes the attribute

```
module="enquireproducts"
```

If that's the case, these modules are dependent on that first module, and disabling that first module will basically break things unless you disable the dependent modules.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I think the previous developer also wrote lots of Magento block rewrite's which screwed up alot of things..